# Individual Accounts in ASP.NET Web API error: username or password is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, authentication

I am following the ASP.NET web api tutorial from 
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api

However, I can't login with the account that I created using Fiddler although I am following the tutorial exactly.  It keeps giving me a 400 error with the error message: username or password is incorrect.

When I checked my SQL database, the username is correct and the password I used to create the test account is 123456...

Basically, I'm trying to get tokens, so I'm only on step 3ish of the tutorial, but it's not working...

Please help!!

Comment: Double check if you included "grant_type=password"

Comment: Yes I did, I also started up a brand new project following the instructions on the tutorial exactly, but still it gives me a username or password is incorrect error message.  I've also added a few break points on the very top of my account controller, but when I run with /Token, it doesn't even hit it and returns the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the project template you're using assumes some type of OAuth authentication (i.e. Facebook, Google, etc.). There is no mapping of /api/Token.

In other words, either the tutorial is wrong or the template changed (making the tutorial wrong).

Answer (score 0):

In fiddler when you put in "grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123" in the Request body make sure there is no space or line break after it.